# Subplots by variable ID on Plotly Express with Python

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I have plot like this:

```
var_names = [i for i in test_df.variable.unique()]
var_names.sort()

fig = px.scatter(test_df, x='date', y='value', color='variable', category_orders={'variable': var_names},
                template="ggplot2", title='Median of access',
                 labels={'value': 'Median of access on the week', 'date': 'Week'}
                 ).update_traces(mode='markers+lines')
fig.show()
```

And my dataframe is:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({
        'ID':list('aabdee'),
        'date':['2020-03-22', '2020-03-22', '2020-03-29', '2020-03-22','2020-03-22', '2020-03-29'],
         'B':[1,0.5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,1,7,1,1],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4]
})
test_df = test_df.melt(['ID', 'date']).
```

I want to run the code just once and build different subplots depending on the ID, like if each graph in the picture below were corresponding to the variables of a specific ID.

I tried with 'add trace' as is on the doc, but if I do this I have to copy and paste the code each time filtering by the ID.

[image]

Comment: Hi Catarina please, provide a [mcve](/help/mcve). In particu;ar it will be great to have a sample of your df `test` so your question will be reproducible and you'll have more chances to get answers.

Comment: Do you mind to edit your question with the expected plot? And then list what you need to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the end was super simple, the problem is that the documentation of plotly express is not so easy to find.

So, you can put the variable facet_col='ID' on your px.scatter(...) and it works :).

Comment: If you want to have control just use `plotly.graph_objs`. If you don't mind I'll add an answer.

Comment: I would like if you can add an answer, I am not aware of that :)

Comment: I also have a problem that the colors are being repeated, if you can add how to avoid this too I will be super grateful :)

Comment: I tried your code and I'm not sure if that is the expected output you are looking for.